# fwrite() and file corruption

Tags: c, fopen, fwrite, fflush

I'm trying to write a wchar array to a file in C, however there is some sort of corruption and unrelevant data like variables and paths like this

```
c.:.\.p.r.o.g.r.a.m. .f.i.l.e.s.\.m.i.c.r.o.s.o.f.t. .v.i.s.u.a.l. .s.t.u.d.i.o. 1.0...0.\.v.c.\.i.n.c.l.u.d.e.\.x.s.t.r.i.n.g..l.i.s.t...i.n.s.e.r.t
```

are written on to the file along with the correct data ([example](http://pastebin.com/Csz94p69)) I have confirmed that the buffer is null-terminated and contains proper data.

Heres my code:

```
        myfile = fopen("logs.txt","ab+");
        fseek(myfile,0,SEEK_END); 
        long int size = ftell(myfile);
        fseek(myfile,0,SEEK_SET);
        if (size == 0)
        {
            wchar_t bom_mark = 0xFFFE; 
            size_t written = fwrite(&bom_mark,sizeof(wchar_t),1,myfile); 
        }
// in another func
            while (true)
            {
            [..]
                unsigned char Temp[512];
                iBytesRcvd = recv(sclient_socket,(char*)&Temp,iSize,NULL);
                if(iBytesRcvd > 0 )
                {
                    WCHAR* unicode_recv = (WCHAR*)&Temp;
                    fwrite(unicode_recv,sizeof(WCHAR),wcslen(unicode_recv),myfile);
                    fflush(myfile);
                }
            [..]
            }
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing wchar_t* with UTF-8?

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger yes I might be, but unsure what to do though

Comment: @Panayiotis what are you *expecting* to be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recv()` will not null-terminate `&Temp`, so `wcslen()` runs over the bytes actually written by `recv()`.  You will get correct results if you just use `iBytesReceived` as byte count for `fwrite()` instead of using `wcslen()` and hoping the data received is correctly null-terminated (wide-NULL-terminated, that is):

```
fwrite(unicode_recv, 1, iBytesReceived, myfile);
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, but no luck still, also to wide-NULL-terminate it I used the last wchar (2 bytes) and set them equal to 0 (00 00) maybe I should have done something else?

Comment: Are you sure that `sizeof(wchar_t)` is `2` and not `4` on your system?

Comment: well int size2 = sizeof(wchar_t); debugged sais its 2 :/

Comment: Impossible to tell what's the problem if you are not showing us the code you are using. In any case, `recv()` is not guaranteed to read the same amount of bytes in one go as you send with `send()` on the other end, so using `wcslen()` as you do is asking for trouble even if the sender would correctly terminate the data it sends and assuming you'd never have malicious senders.

Comment: I found the mistake and it was in the sender after all, due to incorrect array boundaries (sorry for that :( ). I'll adopt your suggestions for this one for safety, thanks for your support

Comment: You probably want your receiver to be resilient against sender mistakes. Or in other words, programming errors in your sender should not be able to crash your receiver.